# What is the use of +(id)function_name in ios

Tags: iphone, ios6

I want to use singleton in my project. So for this I have read about this and find something like this:

```
@interface MyManager : NSObject
{
    NSString *someProperty;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *someProperty;

+ (id)sharedManager;
```

I know we used this to shared some data in our code. Now my question is what is meaning of +(id) and what we called it and what are uses of it

Comment: Why my question getting down vote. Could you specify the reason?

Answer (score 2):

`id` means a reference to an Objective-C object of which the class is unknown. For your example you could also use:

```
+ (MyManager *)sharedManager;
```

Be aware that you don't use a `*` sign with `id`.

`+` means it's a class-method: a method you call on a class like `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", 1]`.

`-` is an instance method, a method you call on an object instance of a class, like '[myString length]'

Answer (score 2):

1. Using `+(id)` makes sure that we do not have to `alloc init` the `Singleton Class` again and gain, as `+` denotes that it is a static method.
2. `+(id)` indicates that the `return type` of the method `+ (id)sharedManager;` can be any object.
3. inside the method `+ (id)sharedManager;` we have to check that the Object is not initialized if the `Singleton instance` of it is already created like - `if(!sharedInstance){
   //Alloc init logic for singleton
   }`.

Comment: Can we change id type to someone like own class name?

Comment: what is use of GCD in + (id)sharedManager ? Can we and how?

Answer (score 1):

The `+` denotes a class method, as opposed to the much more common instance methods, which start with a `-`. (`id`) indicates that this method returns an Objective-C object.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the fzwo response; usually when a class method signature starts with `shared` it means that this class is compliant with the [Singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern). A singleton object has one and only one instance of itself. You can see an example when you use `[UIApplication sharedApplication]`, this returns the singleton application instance.

Comment: Please note though that this is just a naming convention; you still have to program it in a way that it does this.

Comment: @fzwo Yes, i know, that's the reason why i've put the word 'usually' :)